# I am stuck with string and array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

I have come across a c++ code:

```
char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
cout << "Greeting message: ";
cout << greeting << endl;
```

output: `Hello`

Since greeting is an array of size 6, displaying greeting should display only "H" because of `greeting[0]` in `cout`, since it is displaying first address of array. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Please clarify why you expect it to display only "H". You are printing `greeting` not `greeting[0]`

Comment: `greeting` decays into a pointer `char *` and the entire string it is pointing to will be printed. Use `cout << greeting[0] << endl;` if you only want to print the first char.

Comment: this is how cout display a character string...Because greeting is a string that's why cout display "Hello" but if you write "greeting[0]" then cout will display 'H' as a character...

Comment: The `operator <<` for `char *` types is overloaded to start at the given address and print characters until a `\0` is found.

Comment: isnt greeting representing the first value of array?

Comment: it's not *representing* the first value of array. The name of the array *decays* to *the pointer* to the first element of the array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying read to get a better understanding of whats going on

Comment: @PrashantSingh: No. Where did you hear that?

Comment: its due to not listening to lectures properly :p

Comment: @PrashantSingh: or your teacher may have explained it incorrectly, which is sadly common.  A *lot* of people get this very simple concept wrong.

Comment: `greeting` is not the same as `greeting[0]` it's `*greeting` that is the same, i.e. `greeting` (the array name) points to the first element basically.

Answer (score 7):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

This means that in the statement

```
cout << greeting << endl;
```

the expression `greeting` is converted from an expression of type `char [6]` to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

The stream operator `<<` is defined such that if it receives an argument of type `char *`, it will write out the *sequence* of characters starting at that address until it sees the 0 terminator; here's a simplistic example of how it might work:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& s, char *p )
{
  while (*p)
    s.put( *p++ );
  return s;
}
```

The real operator definition will be a bit more complex, but that's the basic idea.

If you want to print out just the first character of `greeting`, you must explicitly index or dereference it:

```
cout << greeting[0] << endl;
```

or

```
cout << *greeting << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`greeting` [**decays to a pointer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) itself. But if it sounds complicated, you can look at it as a pointer to understand what `cout` does.

`cout` method prints characters starting from `greeting[0]` until `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the address value write

```
char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
cout << "Greeting message: ";
cout << (void*)greeting << endl;
     // ^^^^^^^
```

The `std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, T type);` provides specializations for the `const char*`, `const char[]` and `char` types.

Answer (score 0):

yes greeting here is a pointer to first element in the array so if you do something like that :
cout << *greeting;
output will be H.
but in reality when you pass it to cout object it's smart enough to know that greeting is not just a pointer but it's more it's a string according to the internal implementation of operator overloading in handling . 
so it's not a problem ,it's just cout can understand it.